# MySQL Alter table add column if not exists

Tags: mysql

i have error with my if.
ERROR is "IF" is not valid in this position, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE...

my code looks like this can you help me please :)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'clients' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'dateOfRegister')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE realestate
    ADD dateOfRegister DATE NOT NULL
END;
```

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'clients' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'dateOfRegister') BEGIN ALTER TABLE realestate ADD dateOfRegister DATE NOT NULL END;    Is the code that i have

Comment: `IF` requires `THEN` and `END IF`

Comment: Is this code in a stored procedure? `IF` statements are not queries, they can only be used in stored programs.

Comment: just trying to do something on my own its not used anywhere

Comment: Why does that matter? It still has to be in a procedure, that's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

add delimter like this to your request.

```
delimiter |
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'clients' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'dateOfRegister')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE realestate ADD dateOfRegister DATE NOT NULL;
END;
delimiter ;
```

***but it seems that your request will not do what you want to do.***
**it is better to create a procedure or a function.**